# Select roles to view this only page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to limit user roles to view special pages of my website in Laravel. So I tried to add a list of roles in edit.blade.php of my page controller :

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">
        <Permision></Permision>
    </label>
    <div class="col-10">
        @foreach($roles as $value)
            <label>{{ Form::checkbox('permission[]', $value->id, false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
                {{ $value->name }}</label>
            <br/>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Also have it on my edit function of the controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $object = Set::find($id);
    $roles = Role::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);

    $page = new \stdClass();
    $page->title = 'edit item';
    $page->form = 'set.form';
    $page->formMethod = 'post';
    $page->formAction = ["SetController@update", $id];
    $page->uploadURL = '';
    $page->submitButton = 'Submit';
    $page->is_edit = 1;



    return view('set.create', compact('page', 'object','roles'));

}
```

Now I have no idea how to save the roles in the database table of this controller and limit the user of the show.blade.php

The problem is how to add available roles in each database table row of this page?

Comment: You can set the additional column role in your users db table and access it by using `Auth::user()->role`

Comment: I have no problem in saving roles or permission I am using this library :  jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\Models\Role , problem is how to select each role to see a special page or not. I do not want to do that in front . I am trying to make it available for admin user to select roles to view that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like **[Spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)**

This package allows you to manage user permissions and roles in a database.

Once installed you can do stuff like this:

```
// Adding permissions to a user
$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');

// Adding permissions via a role
$user->assignRole('writer');

$role->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

Because all permissions will be registered on Laravel's gate, you can check if a user has a permission with Laravel's default can function:

```
$user->can('edit articles');
```

---

If you want to build your own Roles-Permissions management you can do something like below:

Create a `roles`, `permissions` table.
Then store each role_id and their permissions in the `roles_permissions` table.

**Note: You can cache this roles_permissions association in `Redis` to avoid repeated DB queries**

You should add the relevant `role id` in the `Users` table.

Now write a function to check if a specific role has permission set.

```
checkUserHasPermission(String $permissionKey, User $user):bool
{
    $rolePermissions = functionToGetPermissionForRole($user->role);
    return (boolean) in_array($permissionKey, $rolePermissions);
}
functionToGetPermissionForRole($roleId):array 
{
// add your logic to return the permissions associated with the specific role id
}
```

Note: *If you're caching your roles_permissions association in Redis, don't forget to update Redis while updating the roles and permissions.*